# Javascript - variable number won't go up

Tags: javascript, variables

I've been making this little script and for some reason, one of the variables won't increase its value.

The code looks like this:

```
function get_swf(mode){
var swf_path;
swf_update(); //Updating max_num
if (location.hash) current = location.hash.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""); //Getting only numbers

switch(mode){
case "random":
    current = Math.floor((Math.random() * max_num) + 1);
    swf_path = "uploads/" + current + ".swf";
break;

case "next":
    current += 1;
    if(current > max_num) current = 1;
    swf_path = "uploads/" + current + ".swf";
break;  
case "previous":
    current -= 1;
    if(current == 0) current = max_num;
    swf_path = "uploads/" + current + ".swf";
break;
}
swfobject.embedSWF(swf_path, "lolswf", "800", "400", "9.0.0");
location.hash = current;
```

}

This code is in a function, variables: `current` and `max_num` are global variables.
Everything works as expected except when the case "next" is called. In this case, the variable `current` is set to value "1" even when it hasn't reached the `max_num`. For example, if I set:

`max_num = 5` and `current = 2`

and I call "next" `current` gets set to 1.

I can't get my head around it, can you please help me?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**

After further examination of my code, I found a line that seems to bug the code.
This line is above the code I have provided. (I have updated the code to the whole function, so you can see)

```
if (location.hash) current = location.hash.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""); //Getting only numbers
```

What I expected from this line is, that it simply overwrites the `current` variable, so a user doesn't always have to start from the beginning. However, why would the `current` have the value "1" even though it should get increased? And why would the other cases work as expected?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: What do you mean by 'the variable "current" stays 1 when it reaches the "max_num"'?  Do you mean when it reaches `max_num` it gets set to 1?  That's what you've asked it to do.

Comment: Have you initialised the variable current somewhere outside this code?

Comment: What is the question? What's going wrong?

Comment: I think I have worded the question wrong, let me edit it. Both variables are declared on first line of the code, out of any functions and both have a set value.

Comment: Updated the question with better explanation. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think we need to see more code. I have tested it in a couple browsers and the 'next' functionality seems to work. The problem may be somewhere else.

Comment: The code you've posted worked fine for me.  Try showing us the whole script.

Comment: I'd agree, the logic is sound, your current variable must be being modified elsewhere

Comment: Ok, I've examined the code further and did some tests and found the line that buggs the code. Didn't see that before O.o Updating the question. Thank you VERY much!

Comment: Question is updated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that "previous" works?  You've tried it with several different starting values of `current`?

Comment: Now that you point that out, no, I'm not... But, why wouldn't it work? I might be missing something there, but what I see is, that the `current` gets a value from the hash (if it exists) and then it works with that value and puts it back. Thank you for your help!

Comment: OK, here's the first thing I would do.  Put a print statement (or whatever) just before the switch block and one just after it, to see the value of `current` at these points.  Then run the script with various values of `current` and with both `"previous"` and `"next"`. This will tell you whether there is actually anything wrong with that block.  Also, while you're there, change the "previous" test from `(current == 0)` to `(current <= 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable:

```
location.hash
```

if it is an integer variable it doesn't support the replace method. Replace method is a property of strings.

Now, when you execute the line:

```
if (location.hash) current = location.hash.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""); //Getting only numbers
```

It actually converts the variable current to empty or 0.

Now in the switch section with the 'next' case, only two statements operate on current:

1. it increments current, i.e., 0 + 1 = 1
2. checks if it is more than max, it sets it to 1

In either of the cases you are getting 1 in your current.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap places with the if and path variable.
What you did was setting current to 1, and then adding it to your swf_path string.

```
case "next":
    current += 1;
    swf_path = "uploads/" + current + ".swf";
    if(current > max_num) current = 1;
break;
```

**Update**

It seems as you are doing the same thing with previous. Use the same fix there

Comment: But surely `max_num` is the **maximum** value that it should take on.

Comment: I don't think so.  The usual practise with rollover counters is to change it, then check to see if the new value is valid and rollover if not.  Then use the value.  That is what the existing code does.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this way, the 'current' could get higher than 'max_num' and it would result in broken import. Thank you though :)

Comment: Yes i have clearly misunderstood your question. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Modulus is always an option if you're just using integers

```
 case "next":
    current = (current+1)%(max_num+1); // the modulus rollover
    if(current == 0) current = 1; // in the case that the remainder is 0
    swf_path = "uploads/" + current + ".swf";
 break;
```

Comment: Would this be better as `current = (current+1)%max_num + 1;`, without the following line?

Comment: Well no, you'd always be adding 1 twice, except for in the case that it reaches max_num

Comment: The `+ 1` inside the brackets performs the increment, while the `+ 1` at the end transforms it from a `0..N-1` count into a `1..N` count.

Comment: Take this example using your formula (current = (current+1)%max_num + 1;): starting values: current=1, max=5. Click Next. (1+1)%5+1  = 2%5+1 =  2+1 = 3    ...   was expecting 2 not 3.

Comment: Good point.  Hmm, I'm sure I've used a one-line form of "increment with modulo, and transform 0-based to 1-based" before, but can't think what it was now.  I'll point out that the form in your answer never gives `current = max_num`, so it will miss a value.  You'll need `...%(max_num+1)`